# How to set up a bash script to run in the background anytime the linux ubuntu server is running

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, background, ip-camera

I have written up a simple bash script that will copy the newest image from my ip camera into a directory, rename the file and delete the old file.  The script loops every 10 seconds.

I want to have this script start running in the background and run continuously all the time that the server is up.

I understand the part about adding a & to the end of the command will cause it to run in the background.

Is init.d the best place to execute this?

I am running ubuntu server.

Comment: Instead of having the script loop, you could create a cron job for it that runs every 10 seconds.

Comment: Except the most frequently a cron job can run is every minute :(

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is normally done by *service scripts*, which you would find under `/etc/init.d`.  Depending on the version, that might be a "System V init script", or one of the systemd scripts.

A simple service script of the sort you are asking about would start automatically (based on comments in the script's header that tell what run-levels it would use), create a file under `/var/run` telling what process-id the script uses (to allow killing it), and run the copying in a loop, calling `sleep 10` to space the timing as indicated.

A typical service script should implement "start", "stop", "restart" and "status".  Not all do, but there is rarely a good reason to not do this.

On my (Debian) system, there is a `README` file in the directory which is a good introduction to the topic.  There are several tutorials available for the topic.  Here are a few:

- [Linux: How to write a System V init script to start, stop, and restart my own application or service](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html)
- [Writing a Linux Startup Script](http://www.krazyworks.com/writing-a-linux-startup-script/)
- [Manage System Startup and Boot Processes on Linux with Upstart](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/404619-manage-system-startup-and-boot-processes-on-linux-with-upstart)